# How to enable C++11 compiler on visual studio 2010 express edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, tbb

I am using tbb::parallel_for function which make use of lambdas. I am getting syntax errors with the following code:

```
void parallel_relax( Class object, std::vector<Vertex *> verList ) {
    tbb::parallel_for (blocked_range<int>(0, verList.size()), [=](const blocked_range<Vertex *>& r) {
        for(Vertex *vit = r.begin(); vit != r.end(); ++vit) {
            Vertex *v = vit;
            object.function(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Syntax Errors:

```
syntax error : '['
1>main.cpp(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
1>main.cpp(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>main.cpp(17): error C2065: 'r' : undeclared identifier
1>main.cpp(17): error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>main.cpp(17): error C2065: 'r' : undeclared identifier
1>main.cpp(17): error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>main.cpp(20): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I think this is the problem with the compiler. How do i get c++11 compiler for visual studio 2010 express edition. Please suggest.

Comment: What are lines 16 and 17?

Comment: "tbb::parallel_for" is line 16 and "for(Vertex *vit = r.begin(); vit != r.end(); ++vit)" is line 17

Comment: so I won't be able to use C++11 because I m on Windows 7 and I can only use Visual Studio 2010? BTW...I don't want to use Eclipse with MinGW G++ cause I find it ugly... :(

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ 2010 Express does contain C++11 features, but not all of them.  Here is a list of what features it supports (as well as VC++ 2012):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Comment: How to enable C++11 features? If it is enabled by default, then why is it giving syntax errors?

Comment: As I said above, not all of them. The list is a little deceiving upon first glance, but further down you can see that support for lambdas in VC10 is only partial, which is why you're getting the syntax error.

Comment: This link seems to list only VS2012,13,15

Answer (score 3):

To get C++11 features you should use the latest version, [Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express).

From [C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx):

> Visual C++ 2010 implemented many features in the C++0x core language specification, which was the precursor to C++11, and Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012 expands on that to include many C++11 features.